# How to uncheck a checkbox?

Tags: c#

Checkbox1 calls photoshop to create pictures to a folder. The code below checks a file in the folder to see if a ID# is present, the ID# is created everytime photoshop creates pictures. If the ID# is present it shows a message box saying that the pictures are present and ask the user do they want to replace the pictures.

```
private void PicCheck()
{
    if (Checkbox1.Checked == true)
    {
        if (File.Exists("path/text.cde"))
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText("path/text.cde");
            bool present = text.IndexOf("ID#??") >= 0;
            if (present == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pictures exist, Replace??", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    Checkbox1.Checked = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.WriteAllText("path/text.cde", ("ID#??"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Problem is that when the ID# is present and the user press No the checkbox doesnt get unchecked and the pictures are created again anyway. What I need is  when the user press no, checkbox1 is deselected and the photoshop process assigned to checkbox1 is skipped. Is this possible? Note: It does this check after the user checked checkbox1  and pressed the create button.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the `Show` method to see whether they have pressed yes or no:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Pictures exist, Replace??", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I knew it was something simple as that. Just couldnt put my finger on it.